# Docker volume is empty for jenkins compose file, not copying any files

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to create a jenkins and nexus integration using docker compose file. Where in my jenkins updated with few plugins using Dockerfile and volume created under /var/lib/jenkins/.

**VOLUME ["/var/lib/jenkins/"]**

in compose file am trying to map my volume to local store /opt/jenkins/

```
jenkins:
  build: ./jenkins
  ports:
    - 9090:8080
  volumes:      
    - /opt/jenkins/:/var/lib/jenkins/
```

But Nothing is copying to my persistence directory(/opt/jenkins/).

I can see in all my jenkins jobs created under _data/jobs/ directory under some volume. not in my volume defined /var/lib/jenkins/

Can any one help me on this why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume):

> Volumes are initialized when a container is created. If the container’s base image contains data at the specified mount point, that existing data is copied into the new volume upon volume initialization. (**Note that this does not apply when mounting a host directory.**)

And in the mount a host directory as data volume:

> This command mounts the host directory, /src/webapp, into the container at /webapp. If the path /webapp already exists inside the container’s image, the /src/webapp mount overlays but does not remove the pre-existing content. Once the mount is removed, the content is accessible again. This is consistent with the expected behavior of the mount command.

So basically you are overlaying (hiding) anything that was in var/lib/jenkins. Can your image function if those things are hidden?